# Teen Summer Learning Programs

Tags: torah-study, product-recommendation, summer

What are some Torah learning programs for high school age boys during the summer? I'm looking specifically for a program (preferably but not necessarily in Israel) for teens who are committed to Torah observance but don't necessarily have the skills of those who have gone to yeshiva their whole lives.

Comment: __Answerers:__ Please do not just give names/pointers (that's the equivalent of a link-only answer); please tell us about the programs and how they address this specific audience.  To keep this from turning into a polling question, answers that don't meet this standard are likely to be removed.

Comment: What age group are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

NCSY kollel- affiliated with Yeshiva University, this is a camp based in Israel where there is time dedicated to studying Torah and traveling the land.

Rabbis include: Rabbi Herschel Schachter, Rabbi Meyer Twersky, Rav Tzvi Sobolofsky

Website: http://kollel.ncsy.org/

**Description**:

> NCSY Kollel divides the day between interactive learning  with
>   renowned educators and competitive sports leagues. Basketball, hockey,
>   football, softball and soccer — NCSY Kollel has it all for you to
>   enjoy while spending the summer growing spiritually in Israel.

Camp morasha kollel program: officially modern orthodox, although on the righter wing side of it. Torah study is a main feature of this program, and the students are exposed to the spiritual guidance and mussar shoomzen of Rav Yitzchok Cohen who's style is very passionate.

Rabbis: Rav Pesach Mendelson, Rav Yitzchok Cohen, Rav Mordechai Willig

**Description**:

> Morasha Kollel offers an unparalleled learning experience with
>   prominent and caring Roshei Yeshiva and Rebbeim. Through intense
>   learning, chavrusa, and shiurim, kollel members develop a deep love
>   and connection to Talmud Torah and yiddishkeit while building their
>   learning skills.

Website: http://campmorasha.com/kollel

Comment: Rabbi Tzvi Sobolofsky is in NCSY Kollel, not in Morasha Kollel. The Rabbis involved in the High School part of Morasha Kollel are Rabbi Yizchak Cohen (of YU) and Rabbi Baruch Pesach Mendelson (MTA)

Comment: Is NCSY Kollel considered Modern Orthodox as well?

Comment: @AviM yes. But on the right wing side of it

Answer (score 0):

Yeshivas Hakayitz in Skokie is one of the largest camps for boys in the Midwest. They have a unique combination of intensive Torah Study, sports, and field trips. Takes place on the Hebrew Theological Campus in Skokie Il. Their program for current 9th boys is called Teen Kollel and the boys have as their Rebbe the well known Rabbi Zvi Zimmerman. Check out his shiurim at Rabbzvizimmerman.com. You can get all the latest camp info at yhk.htc.edu.